# How can I split "Segment" to two "Segments"? c++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, vector

given the following classes:

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

enum TypeSeg {
    OPEN, CLOSE, CLOSE_LEFT, CLOSE_RIGHT
};

template<class T>
class Segment {
    T left;
    T right;
    TypeSeg typeS;
public:
    Segment(T left, T right, TypeSeg typeS) :
            left(left), right(right), typeS(typeS) {
    }
    //.....
};

template<class T>
class SegCollection {
    vector<Segment<T>> segments;
public:
//.....
};
```

So that Segment describes segment `?left, right?` while:
if typeS==OPEN so : `(left,right)`.
if typeS==CLOSE so : `[left,right]`.
if typeS==CLOSE_LEFT so : `[left,right)`.
if typeS==CLOSE_RIGHTso : `(left,right]`.

and SegCollection describes collection of segments so that:
The SegCollection no contains two same segments , and no contains two segments with intersect (it will contain the union of them instead) and even no contains two segments like that: `[1,4)` and `[4,5)` (for example) , but, it will contain `[1,5)`.

How can I implement `operator-()` for SegCollection that delete segment from SegCollection so that: this segment not must be in SegCollection, but,  all the points (from all the segments in SegCollection) that exists in SegCollection *and* in the deleted segment will be removed from the segments that exists in SegCollection.

For example:  given: `[1,7] , [9,12]` , if we will remove `(2,5)` , so we will get: `[1,2] , [5,7] , [9,12]`.

I don't know (I thought about it some hours..) how can I treat in the case that I need to split segment following remove of segment (like `[1,7]` in the example , that changed to `[1,2] , [5,7]`)?

Note: Segment is a template-class because that it's can be from (int, int) , (float,float) e.g.

Comment: Usually, you first try to do the job by hand. Then, writte the code for it.

Comment: @Ripi2 What you mean?

Comment: Using some examples, were you able to do it with just paper and pencil? Can you explain how did you do it, which were the steps?. Use the [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: @Ripi2 I am sorry, but I still don't understand what you want (Namely, I know what you mean while you say "Use the rubber duck" , but I did it, like you can see from my question, but I still don't know how to do it)

Comment: You're asking for several tasks: Searching for startting/ending points, comparing,  deleting, replacing, joining, etc. Think about each task and then writte code for every one of them. Divide and conquer.

Comment: @Ripi2 I ask for only one task. In case that I want to remove from my SegCollection = `[2,7] , [10,15]`  , the segment `(3,5)` , how can I acheive from `[2,7]` the segments `[2,3] , [5,7]` (after the removing) ?

Comment: Add two new segments. The start/end points are thouse of the (3,5). Just be aware of the 'types' for these new segments-

Comment: @Ripi2 Ok, I will be try it (By the way, in your opinion, it's ok to define the vector as vector of `Segments` or it is better that each element will be `Segment*` ?)

Comment: You are going to modify or delete Segments only inside your class. Why would you need pointers?

Comment: I exactly thought like you, I only wanted to be sure that it's ok :)

Comment: @Ripi2 In fcat, how can you do it from SegCollection? "Add two new segments" , but how can you acheive these two segments?

Answer (score 0):

This tip may help.

```
template<typename T>
class SegCollection {
    vector<Segment<T>> segments;
public:
    void push_back(Segment<T> seg)
    {
        segments.push_back(seg);
    }

    const SegCollection& operator-(const Segment<T> seg) 
    {  
        // implement some rules that recognize field 
        // TypeSeg and depending on it, changing segments' content
        // ...
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Below find the very short application of your assumptions. I have changed class to struct due to the access reasons (you could leave class but you need to provide with some getters in order to have access to the private members)

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using std::vector;

enum TypeSeg {
    OPEN, CLOSE, CLOSE_LEFT, CLOSE_RIGHT
};

template<typename T>
struct Segment {
    T left;
    T right;
    TypeSeg typeS;

    Segment(T left, T right, TypeSeg typeS) :
            left(left), right(right), typeS(typeS) {
    };
};

template<typename T>
struct SegCollection {

    vector<Segment<T>> segments;

    void push_back(Segment<T> seg)
    {
        segments.push_back(seg);
    }

    const SegCollection& operator-(const Segment<T> seg) 
    { 
        //Find segment that could be divided
        auto it = std::find_if(segments.begin(), segments.end(),
                          [&seg](auto i){ 
                              if (i.left <= seg.left)
                                 if (seg.right <= i.right) 
                                     return true;
                              return false;
                        });

        //If not found, return *this
        if (it == segments.end())
        {
            std::cout << "Cannot do this, Bro." << std::endl;
            return *this;
        }

        //Set boundaries for new segments
        int new_right = it->left + seg.left - it->left;            
        int new_left = seg.right;

        // Here you have to apply other conditions
        // I have used only one case - as you have mentioned in your post
        if (seg.typeS == OPEN)
        {
            Segment<T> seg_first(it->left, new_right, CLOSE);
            Segment<T> seg_second(new_left, it->right, CLOSE);
            *it = seg_second;
            this->segments.insert(it, seg_first);   

        } 

        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you show how you can to treat the following case? In case that I want to remove from my SegCollection = `[2,7] , [10,15]`  , the segment `(3,5)` , how can I acheive from `[2,7]` the segments `[2,3] , [5,7]` (after the removing) ?

Comment: I don't like this idea because that you writted all `Segment` as public, and it's not good idea..

Comment: As I have mentioned you should include some getters (public methods that enables you to get private member variables) if you would like to use classes and private members as well.